# Is it possible for an iOS app to take an image and then analyze the colors present in said image?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

For example after taking the image, the app would tell you the relative amount of red, blue, green, and yellow present in the picture and how intense each color is.

That's super specific I know, but I would really like to know if it's possible and if anyone has any idea how to go about that.

Thanks!

Comment: You should mark your question as answer. Duncan provided a great answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it's possible. You've have to load the image into a UIImage, then get the underlying CGImage, and get a pointer to the pixel data. If you average the RGB values of all the pixels you're likely to get a pretty muddy result, though, unless you're sampling an image with large areas of strong primary colors.

Erica Sadun's excellent iOS Developer Cookbook series has a section on sampling pixel image data that shows how it's done.  In recent versions there is a "core" and an "extended" volume. I *think* it's in the Core iOS volume. My copy of Mac iBooks is crashing repeatedly right now, so I can't find it for you. Sorry about that.

### EDIT:

I got it to open on my iPad finally. It is in the Core volume, in recipe 1-6, "Testing Touches Against Bitmap Alpha Levels." As the title implies, that recipe looks at an image's alpha levels to figure out if you've tapped on an opaque image pixel or missed the image by tapping on a transparent pixel. You'll need to adapt that code to come up with the average color for an image, but Erica's code shows the hard part - getting and interpreting the bytes of image data. That book is all in Objective-C. Post a comment if you have trouble figuring it out.

Comment: See my edit. I found the recipe I was talking about in Erica Sadun's book.